# PyQt5 Vertical TabBar CSS Style

Tags: python, css, pyqt5, styles

I have a app that i designed and I'm trying to style 2 different kinds of Tabs (Horizontal and Vertical) with 2 different kinds of style sheets.

The problem is that to style TabBars you basically have to do:

```
/******************** TAB BAR ***********************/
QTabBar::tab{color:white; background:#292929; border:1px solid white; border-bottom-color:#292929;     border-top-left-radius:4px; border-top-right-radius:4px; padding:2px; margin-bottom:-2px;}
QTabBar::tab:selected {font-weight:bold; border-color:white; border-bottom-color:#292929;} /* same as pane color */
QTabBar::tab:!selected{margin-top:3px;} /* make non-selected tabs look smaller */
```

Which applies to ALL TabBars (Vertical and Horizontal).

[image]

[image]

But i want a different style for vertical / horizontal.

I tried:

Creating a new placeholder classes QVerticalTabWidget(QTabWidget) and QVerticalTabBar(QTabBar)
importing these 2 in QtDesigner and then changing the CSS above to:

```
/******************** TAB BAR ***********************/
QVerticalTabBar::tab{color:white; background:#292929; border:1px solid white; border-bottom-color:#292929;     border-top-left-radius:4px; border-top-right-radius:4px; padding:2px; margin-bottom:-2px;}
QVerticalTabBar::tab:selected {font-weight:bold; border-color:white; border-bottom-color:#292929;} /* same as pane color */
QVerticalTabBar::tab:!selected{margin-top:3px;} /* make non-selected tabs look smaller */
```

Doesn't work.

I tried:

```
/******************** TAB BAR ***********************/
QTabWidget#NAME QTabBar::tab{color:white; background:#292929; border:1px solid white; border-bottom-color:#292929;     border-top-left-radius:4px; border-top-right-radius:4px; padding:2px; margin-bottom:-2px;}
QTabWidget#NAME QTabBar::tab:selected {font-weight:bold; border-color:white; border-bottom-color:#292929;} /* same as pane color */
QTabWidget#NAME QTabBar::tab:!selected{margin-top:3px;} /* make non-selected tabs look smaller */
```

Doesn't work.

As you can see in the picture above, the horizontal tabs look ok, but the vertical is shit.
How can i fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "importing these 2 in QtDesigner"? Also, if you change the orientation, then you obviously cannot use the same positions, and you have to *rotate* them based on the position: since you're using the `West` orientation, turn everything counterclockwise, then what was left, becomes bottom, what was top becomes left, etc.

Comment: You can add custom classes in the Qt Designer and then promote widgets to these imported classes. For example i created this QVerticalTabWidget in a python file (internally it only inherits QTabWidgets and adds nothing, virtually just copying with a new name), added that python file in the Designer, and then "promoted" a QTabWidget to a QVerticalTabWidget. The hope was that CSS would handle this widget differently.

Comment: Also you did not answer my question. I cannot have 2 different CSS styles for the same Widget type, unless i specify the widget name. But that cannot be achieved with QTabBar because QTabBars are inherited by QTabWidgets and have no name.

Comment: Ex: you can have a specific style for QTabWidget#example1 and QTabWidget#example2 because they are 2 different widgets... but QTabBars don't exist as separate independent, named widgets, they are just inherited by each QTabWidget (as in each QTabWidget contains a QTabBar).

So i cannot add styles to them independently.

Comment: I believe you're making some confusion, at least in terminology (which is important). First of all, those are promoted widgets, not "imported in Designer": you'll be using an existing widget type in Designer that acts as a placeholder until the ui is actually loaded in the program. Then, QTabBar does not *inherit* from QTabWidget, it's a *child* of it: therefore, you *can* set different stylesheets for child widgets if you use the proper [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types): in this case, you must use `QTabWidget#NAME > QTabBar::tab {...}`.

Comment: Considering the above, using a promoted class is pointless, if you're using it only as a way to change the behavior of QSS (besides, nothing stops you to set specific stylesheets for those tabwidgets). In any case, a promoted widget should be used only to add functionalities in the initialized object or implement special behavior. Even assuming you prefer to specify the tabBar QSS selector, using an empty class is useless: a proper solution would have been to use `self.tabBar().setObjectName(...)` in the promoted class (for instance, by overriding `setObjectName()` and using a derivate name).

Comment: Yea i confused some terminologies but you got my point :)

`self.tabBar().setObjectName(...)`

hmm haven't considered this. I'll try it.

`QTabWidget#NAME > QTabBar::tab {...}`

I tried `QTabWidget#NAME QTabBar::tab {...}` but that didn't work...

I noticed now the page you linked and it makes a lot more sense. It should work now.

I'll try it on Monday and come back with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/******************** VERTICAL TAB WIDGETS / BARS ***********************/
QTabWidget#NAME::pane {background: #292929; border: 1px white;}
QTabWidget#NAME::tab-bar {background: #292929; min-height: 800px;}
QTabWidget#NAME > QTabBar::tab{color:white; background:#292929;}
QTabWidget#NAME > QTabBar::tab:selected{color: #6856B8; font-weight:bold;}
QTabWidget#NAME > QTabBar::tab:!selected{color: white;}

/******************** HORIZONTAL TAB WIDGETS / BARS ***********************/
QTabWidget::pane {background:  #292929; border: 1px solid white;}

QTabWidget#NAME2::tab-bar {min-width: 300px;}
QTabWidget#NAME3::tab-bar {min-width: 600px;}
QTabWidget#NAME4::tab-bar {min-width: 200px;}

QTabWidget#NAME2 > QTabBar::tab,
QTabWidget#NAME3 > QTabBar::tab,
QTabWidget#NAME4 > QTabBar::tab
{color:white; background:#292929; border:1px solid white; border-bottom-color:#292929; border-top-left-radius:4px; border-top-right-radius:4px; padding:2px; margin-bottom:-2px;}

/* same as pane color */
QTabWidget#NAME2 > QTabBar::tab:selected,
QTabWidget#NAME3 > QTabBar::tab:selected,
QTabWidget#NAME4 > QTabBar::tab:selected
{font-weight:bold; border-color:white; border-bottom-color:#292929;} 

/* make non-selected tabs look smaller */
QTabWidget#NAME2 > QTabBar::tab:!selected,
QTabWidget#NAME3 > QTabBar::tab:!selected,
QTabWidget#NAME4 > QTabBar::tab:!selected
{margin-top:3px;}
```

Achieved what i was trying to do.

Thanks @[musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante)  for the help.